# Little endian calculation of binary value

Tags: c, endianness

Suppose integer is 2 bytes and I want to store 769. In binary , it will be stored as 00000011 00000001

If I convert it to little endian , then it should be stored as 
00000001 00000011 . Here after storing it in this way, the value of binary number should be 49280 (from left to right ). Even if I calculate from right to left, it's not same as 769.

Does the compiler again rearrange the bytes to calculate the correct value ? In that case big endian would be better than little endian I guess.

Comment: Big endian and little endian tells us how bytes are stored in memory, not how values are calculated.

Comment: But the values are calculated based on the data in the memory right ?

Comment: There are no calculations done in memory. And in C it is all about values, 2 + 2 is 4, however the bytes are stored.

Comment: `00000001 00000011` is 259 not 49280, 49280 is `11000000 10000000,` it seems that you are reversing also the bits of each byte, the endian order refers to bytes and not to bits.

Comment: I am not reversing the order of bits. It is (2^7 + 2^14 + 2^15) = 49280. If you see from right to left then it's 259. But in both cases it's not 769, that's my point.

Comment: I mean: the reverse  endian order of `00000011 00000001` (769) is `000000001 00000011` (259), `11000000 10000000` (49280) is the result of reversing the bytes and also the bits of each byte.

Comment: I got 49280 by starting the numbering from left to right . I thought that as the bytes are stored from LSB to MSB, numbering from left to right would make sense. But it doesn't work either. Can you tell me how does the compiler actually calculate the value?

Comment: The bytes (not the bits) are "reordered' inside the CPU when calculations are done. And the compiler uses the CPU for all calculation. You're right on one point : if two diffrent CPUs were accessing to the same memory, one little endian and one big endian CPU, they won't see the same value at the same place when working on more than one byte.

Answer (score 0):

The big endian & little endian describe the storage of memory management that how the "bytes" are stored in memory .It doesnot mean that the calculation .
& you can interchange the bytes after the processors cycle.You can do it wrong because you interchange the bytes before the processors execution thats why it give the wrong value !

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't run the program, Compiler generates an executable from the source code, Executables reside in memory. Processer fetches the executable instruction by instruction and perform the instructed operations.

Now what is executable ? executable is nothing but a sequence of machine (processor) instructions.

Little endian machine read/write LSB of integer first. Whereas big endian read/write MSB first.

In your example 769 LE machine will write 00000001 byte first and hence it stores at lower address '2540'. BE machine will write MSB first (00000011 stored at '2540'.

```
---------------------------------------------
addr  |    2540        |     2541         |  2542
---------------------------------------------
LE    |   00000001     |   00000011       |            
BE    |   00000011     |   00000001       |
   ->  1st byte R/W      2nd byte R/W
```